# How I can add action to title of NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uinavigationbar

I want to give/add action to the title of navigation title.
(Example "Explore")

[image]

I want to perform some activity using this approach.

I tried following code, but it's not working.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(touchedOnNavigationTitle:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Explore" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    //[view addSubview:button];
    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:button];

-(void)touchedOnNavigationTitle:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked on Navigation Title");
}
```

ViewController name is came from presentViewController type not from push.navigationController stack.

How I can achieve this using objective-C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`titleView` is `nil` by default.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview

You should set your title view with your button. Not add it as a subview.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = button
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with the following:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(touchedOnNavigationTitle:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Explore" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.titleView = button;

-(void)touchedOnNavigationTitle:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked on Navigation Title");
}
```